# VHDL-how to do rising edge clock statement?

Tags: vhdl

hello I need to make statment using rising edge of clock in vhdl . How ever as I understand I cant do statment of rising edge within statment of rising edge ... for example this is my code :

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;

entity DFF_8bit is 

    GENERIC ( display_resulation: INTEGER :=8); 

   port(


        CLK_50M_hZ :in std_logic;
        Rising_Edge_Signal :in std_logic; 


        Q : out std_logic_vector(display_resulation-1 downto 0);
        Bit_out : out std_logic;


      D:in std_logic_vector(display_resulation-1 downto 0)
   );
end DFF_8bit;




architecture Behavioral of DFF_8bit is  


signal flag : std_logic_vector(display_resulation-1 downto 0):="0";


begin  



    D_0_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal'event and Rising_Edge_Signal='1') ) then


                    Q(0) <=D(0); 
                    Flag(0)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(0)<='0';

                end if;       
    end if ;
```

I get this error:

```
Error: couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge
```

is there any other way ?

--edit -full code ...

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;

entity DFF_8bit is 

    GENERIC ( display_resulation: INTEGER :=8); 

   port(


        CLK_50M_hZ :in std_logic;
        Rising_Edge_Signal :in std_logic;       
        Q : out std_logic_vector(display_resulation-1 downto 0);
        Bit_out : out std_logic;
      D:in std_logic_vector(display_resulation-1 downto 0)
   );
end DFF_8bit;




architecture Behavioral of DFF_8bit is  


signal flag : std_logic_vector(display_resulation-1 downto 0):="00000000";


begin  



    D_0_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D,Flag)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal='1' )  then    
                    Q(0) <=D(0); 
                    Flag(0)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(0)<='0';
                end if;       
    end if ;            
 end process D_0_bit;  




    D_1_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D,Flag)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal='1' ) then     
                    Q(1) <=D(1); 
                    Flag(1)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(1)<='0';   
                end if;       
    end if ;            
 end process D_1_bit;  





    D_2_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D,Flag)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal='1' ) then     
                    Q(2) <=D(2); 
                    Flag(2)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(2)<='0';   
                end if;       
    end if ;            
 end process D_2_bit;  




    D_3_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D,Flag)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal='1' ) then
                    Q(3) <=D(3); 
                    Flag(3)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(3)<='0';
                end if;       
    end if ;            
 end process D_3_bit;  



    D_4_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D,Flag)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal='1' ) then
                        Q(4) <=D(4); 
                    Flag(4)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(4)<='0';   
                end if;       
    end if ;            
 end process D_4_bit;  




    D_5_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D,Flag)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal='1' ) then     
                    Q(5) <=D(5); 
                    Flag(5)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(5)<='0';   
                end if;       
    end if ;            
 end process D_5_bit;  






    D_6_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D,Flag)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal='1' ) then     
                    Q(6) <=D(6); 
                    Flag(6)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(6)<='0';   
                end if;       
    end if ;            
 end process D_6_bit;  






    D_7_bit:process(Rising_Edge_Signal,CLK_50M_hZ,D,Flag)
 begin 
    if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then
                if(Rising_Edge_Signal='1' ) then     
                    Q(7) <=D(7); 
                    Flag(7)<='1';
                ELSE 
                    Flag(7)<='0';   
                end if;       
    end if ;            
 end process D_7_bit;  


    Bit_out_test :process(Rising_Edge_Signal,flag,CLK_50M_hZ,Flag)
  begin 
      if((CLK_50M_hZ'event and CLK_50M_hZ='1') ) then



                    Bit_out<=flag(0) and flag(1) and flag(2) and flag(3) and flag(4) and flag(5) and flag(6) and flag(7);


        end if ; 
   end process Bit_out_test ;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: What was wrong with have only the CLK signal in your sensitiviy list, and then the first line of your process as: if ( rising_edge(Clk) ) then

Comment: I did not understand your comment ...

Comment: No, there is no hardware which represents that behavior, You can try make a new clock based on the two signals but that will be have different behavior as what you are trying to do. Anyway: making 'derived clocks' (A clock which is derived in any way from signals and/or the system clock) is something you should use only as last resort. Why don't you tell us in words what you are trying to do and we might be able to tell you how to do it.

Comment: ok I will try to explain what I want to do . so I want to build a 8bit FLIP FLOP .  so I get data FROM adc in the input (my input of the DFF is d ) and using the signal Rising_Edge_Signal the data is transformed from d to q . by the time the data transforms from d to q I want to get signal that is showing when the data is transformed from d to q . in order to do this I got signal flag . that when d goes to q then the flag gets '1' and when varible flag gets '11111111' then make signal Bit_out='1' else Bit_out='0'.

Comment: While you're at it, please format your code to something readable

Comment: Sorry at work, not much time for long answer: synchronize you 'ready' flag to the local clock, make an edge detector, read the parallel data when the edge seen. But this only works if local clock is 2xhigher then ADC clock.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is so badly written it's making my eyes bleed.

You don't need a separate process for every bit, especially given that the logic in all of them is exactly the same. And you certainly don't need N copies of "flag", since they all do exactly the same thing. The whole thing reduces to:

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;

entity DFF_8bit is 
  GENERIC (display_resulation: INTEGER := 8);  
  port (
    CLK_50M_hZ         : in  std_logic;
    Rising_Edge_Signal : in  std_logic; 
    Q                  : out std_logic_vector (display_resulation-1 downto 0);
    Bit_out            : out std_logic;
    D                  : in  std_logic_vector (display_resulation-1 downto 0)
  );
end DFF_8bit;

architecture Behavioral of DFF_8bit is
  signal flag : std_logic;
begin
  process (Rising_Edge_Signal, CLK_50M_hZ, D, Flag)
  begin
    if (rising_edge (CLK_50M_hZ)) then
      if (Rising_Edge_Signal = '1') then
        Q <= D;
      end if;
      flag <= Rising_Edge_Signal;
      Bit_out <= flag;
    end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

This is a whole lot easier for someone else to read and understand.

Comment: +1 The sensitivity list only needs the clock. You know, in case OP wants to actually simulate his design before synthesis (which seems optimistic).

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want to detect the rising edge of the Rising_Edge_Signal. @dave-tweed already offered some good tips on your code overall so i'll start from his suggestion. I'll create a separate process, just for sake of clarity, that delays the input signal by one clock cycle and compares if the leading signal is high while the delayed is low and hence a rising edge occured.

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;

entity DFF_8bit is    GENERIC (display_resulation: INTEGER := 8);     port (
    CLK_50M_hZ         : in  std_logic;
    Rising_Edge_Signal : in  std_logic; 
    Q                  : out std_logic_vector (display_resulation-1 downto 0);
    Bit_out            : out std_logic;
    D                  : in  std_logic_vector (display_resulation-1 downto 0)   ); end DFF_8bit;

architecture Behavioral of DFF_8bit is   
 signal flag : std_logic;
 signal rising_edge_detected : std_logic; 
 signal Rising_Edge_Signal_d : std_logic; 
 begin   
  rising_edge_detector:process (CLK_50M_hZ) begin
   if (rising_edge (CLK_50M_hZ)) then
     Rising_Edge_Signal_d <= Rising_Edge_Signal;
     if (Rising_Edge_Signal_d = '0' and Rising_Edge_Signal ='1' ) then
       rising_edge_detected <= '1';
     else
       rising_edge_detected <= '0';
     end if; 
   end if;
  end process rising_edge_detector;

   process (CLK_50M_hZ)   begin
    if (rising_edge (CLK_50M_hZ)) then
      if (rising_edge_detected = '1') then
        Q <= D;
      end if;
      flag <= Rising_Edge_Signal;
      Bit_out <= flag;
    end if;   
   end process; 
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: -1: Random use of multiple processes is *less clear* once you get to designs of actual size and is a habit that should be kicked to the curb as soon as possible.

Comment: it's not random in this case. I think it is fine since you are doing two things that are logically independent and providing different outcomes. Moreover, i explicitly said in my comment that it is just for the sake of clarity to highlight the modifications that i did to the design